# How can I find $\lim_{|z|\to 0}|\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z}|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

In calculation of a contour integral, I need to find 
$$\lim_{|z|\to 0}\bigg|\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z}\bigg|.$$

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then
$$
\lim_{|z|\to 0}\bigg|\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z}\bigg|=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{|1-e^{2ir(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}|}{r}
=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{|1-e^{-2r\sin\theta+2ir\cos\theta}|}{r}
$$

> How can I go on with this calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** use Taylor expansion of $e^x$:
$$e^{2iz}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(2iz)^n}{n!}=1+2iz+\frac{(2iz)^2}2+\dots$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{|z| \to 0}\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z}$$ is by definition the derivative of $-e^{2iz}$ at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The function 
$$
f(z)=e^{2i\pi z}
$$
is entire and $f'(z)=2i\pi e^{2i\pi z}$.

In particular, it is differentiable at $0$ where
$$
2i\pi=f'(0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{2i\pi z}-1}{z}
$$

I'm sure you can conclude now.